# Развернуть окно в winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать так , что бы нельзя было развернуть программу на весь экран в winforms?

P.S. Я про это:

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: MaximizeBox = false

Comment: Ненавижу, когда окна нельзя максимизировать и ресайзить...

Comment: @Qwertiy Почему? И я это сделал , потому что не знаю как оптимизировать её под весь экран(моя более-менее полезная программа)

Comment: Потому что бесит скроллить всякие мелкие списки, когда на экране полно неиспользуемого места...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В свойствах:

```
MaximizeBox = false;
```

Comment: Странные люди люди люди .... всё равно что кого-то продублировать  
MaximizeBox = false – Digital Core